# PRESS statistic and k-fold cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, training-error

How is the PRESS statistic calculated in a k-fold cross-validation? I know how it is done in the leave-one-out scenario. Is it still summed over all training samples, just that there are now k-many partial sums instead of n-many (LOOCV)?

Comment: PRESS is calculated over the predictions of the left out cases, not the training cases.

Comment: I meant summed up over all training samples, i.e. training n-times with one sample left out, and then summing up, which leads to n summands. How does that work when more than a single sample is left out at a time?